# if $R$ is Noetherian local with a finite module of finite injective dimension and if "?" , then $R$ is "Gorenstein"

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay-rings

I know that [if $R$ is Noetherian local with a finite module of finite injective dimension, then *$R$ is Cohen-Macaulay*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710644/does-operatornameid-m-dim-r-hold-for-finite-modules-of-finite-injective-d).

> Can one add assumptions on $M$, so that $R$ be *Gorenstein* or *Complete intersection* or *Regular*?

thank you.

Comment: Could you be more precise (I suppose you do not allow to add conditions like $M$ free).

Comment: i mean nontrivial assumptions.

Comment: I mean that I do not know in what kind of conditions are you thinking. For instance, the change from $M$ free to pd$M$ finite (Foxby) may seem a standard improvement, I do not know if you are interested in classes of modules as "test modules" (there is not a standard definition of test module, but see for instance arXiv:1405.5188), etc.

Comment: @Vinteuil your answer is good but i can not read french. if the proof is short can you please write it here (in english)?

Comment: If $R$ has dimension $1$ and $M$ is reflexive, then $R$ is Gorenstein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you admit $M$ cyclic as additional assumtion, then $R$ is Gorenstein by a theorem  in Peskine-Szpiro paper "Dimension projective finie et cohomologie locale", Theorem II.5.5.

Comment: thank you. do you have a link? (in english)

Comment: No. You can find the original (in french) in numdam.org.

Answer (score 2):

To complete *Vinteuil*'s answer:
 You can find translation of "*Local cohomology and finite projective dimension*", by *C. Peskine and L. Szpiro*, [here](http://www.math.unl.edu/~siyengar2/Papers/Ihes.pdf). (Translator is  [Srikanth B. Iyengar](http://www.math.unl.edu/~siyengar2/)).